# Toilet keeps running

Tags: toilet

I did the color dye test in the tank and yes, there was color dye in the toilet bowl. Very slight but need to get it fixed. You really can't hear it but when I removed the top from the tank I could hear a slight hissing.  I pulled up the float and the noise stopped. How do I adjust the Floater to a slightly higher level?

Comment: superglue a styrofoam chunk to the bottom of the float if it can't be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

If the color from the tank ended up in the bowl, then the flapper or seal is probably bad. Turn off the shutoff valve and see if the water level in the tank drops. If it does, bad flapper/seal.

To adjust the float bend the float rod down or if it's a plastic valve, there's an adjustment screw on the side that you' want to turn it counterclockwise. Pictures would help.

Comment: I agree it’s usually the flapper unless water is going over the top then there could be 1/2 a dozen different adjustments depending on model or brand.